# Domain continues answering even after deleted DNS zones

Tags: domain-name-system

I have a CentOS server... I deleted the dns zones from a domain, but it is still working... Is this normal? The domain to continue answering even after deleted its dns zones?

Answer (score 3):

You have to do two checks:

1- You need to restart/reload the name server after changing the configuration (including zone file change).

2- You need to wait for the record timeout before seeing the new change. The TTL value is specified usually in the zone file. Look at [this link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zone_file) (file format section). You can flush your DNS cache on your local machine, but you can not flush the DNS cache on an intermediate DNS server between your machine and your DNS server (if any).

Comment: Really sounds like the OP needs to reload his dns config to pick up the changes.

Answer (score 2):

The old zone information might still be in your local DNS cache.

If you are using a browser to test, you may have to clear your browsing history or restart the browser in order to flush the old information.  Alternately, you could use the dig command - it queries the current DNS information directly.

Answer (score 0):

You omitted what DNS software you are using. Is it Bind, PowerDNS, DJBDNS, or something else?

In any case, simply deleting a file is not likely to be enough to make the change. Typically, you will have to reload the software in some way to force it to reread the zone files or configuration.

I'm going to guess you're using Bind. I don't remember exactly which scripts exist on Redhat, but here's an example. A very blunt method would be to simply restart it with "/etc/init.d/bind-server restart" or "service restart bind-server". With Bind, you should also be able to control the daemon with the utility "rndc". Check the rndc manpage for more information.